# How to add a plugin system to an application made with Express and React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, express

I want to be able to make plugins (of comments, games, communities, etc.) available separately from the main application, and besides me that other developers can create plugins to sell.
It is basically like the WordPress plugin system.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of plugins do you want. If they are like manipulating objects in programming language, you might want to consider creating different libraries in javascript which can be shared between Express and React. But if they are UI components, you can create a separate npm package and import it in your react app. But these cannot be used in the `Express` node.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a bunch of plugins in ReactJS and dynamically import the relevant/purchased ones using [React.lazy](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy). If you can implement a database into your system architecture you can use that to keep track of which plugins each user has purchased and should import.

Comment: That's not actually dynamic. You have to know at compile time what plugins to load. And you need to recompile the app. A plugin system should not require any change to the app core or recompilation.